# Transpose of a vector in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am fairly new to coding in the python3 language. I'm trying to take the transpose of a vector and multiply it by another vector and print the result  I am not too sure how to do this any help would be appreciated I'm trying to take the transpose of vector01 so it can be of compatible dimensions with vector 2 so I can compute their product.

```
def transpose(vector):
    for i in range(len(vector01):
        total = 0
        for j in range(len(vector02):
            total += vector01[i] * vector02[i]
        result.append(total)
    return result
vector01 = [1, 0, 1]
vector02 = [2, 3, 4] 
print(transpose(vector))
```

Comment: please provide full code that you are running, python does not have vectors, just lisys, unless you use numpy

Comment: also inside your functions vector01 and vector02 are undefined